# How can I optimize my app to run more smoothly?

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, memory

When the back button is pressed in my application, a delegate is called. All functions properly, however there is a large delay between the transition of the view. This gives the user a feeling that the app is crashed or isn't functioning properly.

The delegate methods that are triggered and causing the delay are shown here.

```
func setValues(obj: overviewProps){
    overview = obj
    print("Values Set")
    surveyToEdit.overview = obj
    updateSurveyObj()
}


func setArray(obj: [areaProps]) {
    areas = obj
    print("Set Array Sucessfully")
    print(areas.count)
    surveyToEdit.areas = obj
    updateSurveyObj()

}

 func saveSurveys(x : addedSurveys){

    let isSuccessfulSave = NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(x, toFile: addedSurveys.ArchiveURL.path)

    if isSuccessfulSave {
        os_log("Surveys Saved", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
    } else {
        os_log("Failed to Save", log: OSLog.default, type: .error)
    }

}

func updateSurveyObj(){
    //this must be the issue
    surveyToEdit.name = surveyToEdit.overview?.name ?? surveyToEdit.name
    surveyToEdit.areas! = areas
    surveyToEdit.overview! = overview
    surveyListSurveys.surveys[surveyIndex] = surveyToEdit
    saveSurveys(x: surveyListSurveys)
    delegate?.saveInfo(updatedArray: surveyListSurveys)

    print("the name is : \(surveyToEdit.overview!.name)")
}
```

When connected to the debugger, the device is showing a high memory usage and high cpu usage during this delay.

Here is the entire view controller for the project overview:

```
import UIKit
```

import os.log

class projectOverview: UIViewController, overviewDelegate, AreaDelegate {

```
var surveyToEdit = survey(areas: nil, settings: nil, overview: nil, name: "New Survey")
let IMG = UIImage(named: "noImage.png")

var areas = [areaProps(x: "New Area", y: "", z: "", a: "", b: "", p1: nil, p2: nil, p3: nil), areaProps(x: "New Area", y: "", z: "", a: "", b: "", p1: nil, p2: nil, p3: nil)]
var settings = companySettings(manager: "")
var overview = overviewProps(x: "", y: "", a: "", b: "", c: "", d: "", e: "", f: "", st: "", ct: "", stt: "")
var projectTitle: String = ""
let areaView = areaDetails()

let surveyHomeScreen = surveyList()
var surveyIndex = 0
var surveyListSurveys = addedSurveys(survey: [survey]())
var delegate:projectDelegate?
// need this to eventually pass back the data in the the survey object

func saveSurveys(x : addedSurveys){

    let isSuccessfulSave = NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(x, toFile: addedSurveys.ArchiveURL.path)

    if isSuccessfulSave {
        os_log("Surveys Saved", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
    } else {
        os_log("Failed to Save", log: OSLog.default, type: .error)
    }

}

func setProjDetails(){
    print("gay")
    if surveyToEdit.areas != nil{
        areas = surveyToEdit.areas!
        print("There is area")
    }
    if surveyToEdit.overview != nil{
        overview = surveyToEdit.overview!
        print("there is overview")
    }
}
func updateSurveyObj(){
    //this must be the issue
    surveyToEdit.name = surveyToEdit.overview?.name ?? surveyToEdit.name
    surveyToEdit.areas! = areas
    surveyToEdit.overview! = overview
    surveyListSurveys.surveys[surveyIndex] = surveyToEdit
    saveSurveys(x: surveyListSurveys)
    delegate?.saveInfo(updatedArray: surveyListSurveys)

    print("the name is : \(surveyToEdit.overview!.name)")
}

let overviewController = addOverview()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //areas = surveyToEdit.areas!
    //overview = surveyToEdit.overview!

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    //overviewController.delegate = self
    //areaView.delegate = self

}

// MARK : - Actions

@IBAction func showPDF(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToShare", sender: self)
    print(overview.name)
}


@IBAction func editAreas(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToServiceArea", sender: self)
}


@IBAction func editOverView(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToMainDetails", sender: self)
}


func setValues(obj: overviewProps){
    overview = obj
    print("Values Set")
    surveyToEdit.overview = obj
    updateSurveyObj()
}

// MARK: - Navigation


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "goToMainDetails"{
        let vc = segue.destination as! addOverview
        vc.overview = overview
        vc.delegate = self
    } else if segue.identifier == "goToServiceArea"{ // this is the segue
        let vc = segue.destination as! areaDetails
        vc.areaArray = self.areas
        vc.delegate = self
        print(" \(areas.count) Areas in Array ") // the array contains only 1 object
    } else {
        let vc = segue.destination as! shareReport
        vc.surveyToDisplay = surveyToEdit

    }
}

override func willMove(toParent parent: UIViewController?) {
    super.willMove(toParent:parent)
    if parent == nil {
        updateSurveyObj()
    }
}
func setArray(obj: [areaProps]) {
    areas = obj
    print("Set Array Sucessfully")
    print(areas.count)
    surveyToEdit.areas = obj
    updateSurveyObj()

}



@IBOutlet var floorPlanIMG: UIImageView!
```

and here is the view that the back button is being pressed on:

```
import UIKit
```

class addOverview: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

var overview = overviewProps(x: "", y: "", a: "", b: "", c: "", d: "", e: "", f: "", st: "", ct: "", stt: "")

```
// MARK: - Init all UIVariables
let buildingTypes = ["Industrial", "School", "Office", "Multi-Tenant", "Church", "Manufacturing", "Misc"]
let cleaningFreqs = ["1/Week", "2/Week", "3/Week", "4/Week", "5/Week", "6/Week", "7/Week", "1/EOW", "1/Month"]
@IBOutlet var datePicker: UIDatePicker!
@IBOutlet var buildingName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var street: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var city: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var State: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var contactName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var phoneNumber: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var email: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var buildingPicker: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet var cleaningFreqPicker: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet var sqFt: UITextField!
var delegate:overviewDelegate?

// MARK: - Conform to PickerView

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if pickerView.tag == 2
    {
        return buildingTypes.count
    }
    else{
        return cleaningFreqs.count
    }
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if (pickerView.tag == 2)
    {
        return buildingTypes[row]
    }else{
        return cleaningFreqs[row]
    }
}





override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    updateView()
    buildingPicker.delegate = self
    cleaningFreqPicker.delegate = self
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if overview.building != ""{
        buildingPicker.selectRow(buildingTypes.index(of: overview.building)!, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
        cleaningFreqPicker.selectRow(cleaningFreqs.index(of: overview.freq)!, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
    }
}



// set all the values of the object

func updateView(){
    buildingName.text = overview.name
    city.text = overview.city
    contactName.text = overview.contact
    email.text = overview.email
    phoneNumber.text = overview.phone
    sqFt.text = overview.sft
    State.text = overview.state
    street.text = overview.street
}

func setValues(){
    overview.name = buildingName.text!
    overview.city = city.text!
    overview.contact = contactName.text!
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"
    overview.date = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
    overview.email = email.text!
    overview.building = buildingTypes[buildingPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
    overview.freq = cleaningFreqs[cleaningFreqPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
    overview.phone = phoneNumber.text!
    overview.sft = sqFt.text!
    overview.state = State.text!
    overview.street = street.text!
}



// MARK: - Navigation

override func willMove(toParent parent: UIViewController?) {
    super.willMove(toParent:parent)
    if parent == nil {
        setValues()
        print("Back Button Pressed")
        delegate?.setValues(obj: overview)
    }
}
// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
```

}

Comment: Please add the whole viewContoller/view's code out here.

Comment: Posted both the parent view and the child from which the back button is being pressed in